# Ordering database elements according to date

Tags: android, sqlite, relational-database

I have to arrange the articles from latest to oldest...I have created a database that contains the article's link and the date at which it was updated.What should be the type for date in database and how can I get data from the database in the order I stated above?

Could Not post code.....
Thanks For the reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many case, the best type for the date is `long` (or `INT` in SQLite) for storing UTC millisecond from epoch. With this, you don't have to worry about the time zone difference.

As for how to get the date ordered from the database, since you are using SQLite, when you query the DB, use `<your date column name> ASC/DESC` for `ORDER BY`.